# djs unmuting user in time (database)

Tags: javascript, discord.js, bots

I want to make a mute command where you can mute a user for a specific time.
I have used a setTimeout() function before but it isnt useful for a bigger time or if the bot stops and start again. So now I am saving the time to a database:

```
expires = new Date(new Date().getTime() + time).toLocaleString()
// -> 9.9.2021, 22:21:34
```

So now I want to unmute this user on 9.9.2021, 22:21:34. The problem is that I dont know how to give the bot a signal that the user has to be unmuted in time. So how to tell the bot when to call the function unmute(). For example if I get the data from the database when the bot is started and the data is: `9.9.2021, 22:21:34`. Now the bot has to call a function at this date. How?

Answer (score 0):

One common approach is to use the database as a message-queue. The bot would "poll" the database at regular intervals to pull relevant events and execute those that are ready. When an event is pulled, it is also deleted from the database.